# Add AD group not working [Powershell command]

Tags: powershell

I am figuring out how to add the AD group to my AD user within the same domain using powershell command but I cant get it work as expected. The example I found was mainly using `DN` instead of `sAMAccountname`. This is the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/add-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) I found in Microsoft website

These are all of my attempt on the powershell command but none of it was working. The powershell CLI was run as an user that contain sufficient privilege for updating the AD

```
Get-ADGroup -Server myserver.com -SearchBase "OU=test,dc=myserver,dc=com" -filter {name -like "groupA"} | Add-ADGroupMember -Members 3090
```

3090 is the user `sAMAccountname`.If I tried   `Get-ADGroup -Server myserver.com -SearchBase "OU=test,dc=myserver,dc=com" -filter {name -like "groupA"}` , its able to return a correct group name but I am not sure why after I added `Add-ADGroupMember -Members 3090`, the command seem like not working anymore. Here are the combination of different command but none of them were working. I need to add the group to user base on `sAMAccountname` or `User Principle Name` instead of `DN` because my users were not located in the same `OU`

Attempt 1

```
 Get-ADGroup -Server myserver.com -SearchBase "OU=test,dc=myserver,dc=com" -filter {name -like "groupA"} | Add-ADGroupMember -Members "3090"
```

Attempt 2

```
  Add-ADGroupMember -Identity groupA -Members 3090
```

Attempt 3

```
$User = Get-ADUser -Identity "3090" -Server "myserver.com"
$Group = Get-ADGroup -Identity "groupA" -Server "myserver.com"
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $User -Server "myserver.com"
```

No error was displayed in my powershell CLI

Comment: Please post the errors you are receiving.

Comment: no error was returned from all my tested command